# Plotting extreme values on a histogram with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Data:**

```
data = data.frame(rnorm(250, 90, sd = 30))
```

I want to create a histogram where I have a bin of fixed width, but all observation which are bigger than `arbitrary number` or lower than `another arbitrary number` are group in their own bins. To take the above data as an example, I want binwidth = 10, but all values above 100 together in one bin and all values bellow 20 together in their own bin.

I looked at some answers, but they make no sense to me since they are mostly code. I would appreciate it greatly if somebody can explain the steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples below show how to create the desired histogram in base graphics and with `ggplot2`. Note that the resulting histogram will be quite distorted compared to one with a constant break size.

### Base Graphics

The R function `hist` creates the histogram and allows us to set whatever bins we want using the `breaks` argument:

```
# Fake data
set.seed(1049)
dat = data.frame(value=rnorm(250, 90, 30))

hist(dat$value, breaks=c(min(dat$value), seq(20,100,10), max(dat$value)))
```

In the code above `c(min(dat$value), seq(20,100,10), max(dat$value))` sets breaks that start at the lowest data value and end at the highest data value. In between we use `seq` to create a sequence of breaks that goes from 20 to 100 by increments of 10. Here's what the plot looks like:

[image]

### ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(value)) +
  geom_histogram(breaks=c(min(dat$value), seq(20,100,10), max(dat$value)),
                 aes(y=..density..), color="grey30", fill=hcl(240,100,65)) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the ggplot example and detailed explanation. How can I make the the 100-160 bar have the same visual width as the others?